# Django m2m through model with classic admin widget

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-widget

I need to customise a through model of a many-to-many relationship, the customisation is subtle, because the user won't need do act manually, I try to explain myself better by explaining my use case with the following pseudo code:

```
RouterConfiguration
- vpn (many-to-many through VpnClient)
# other fields

VpnClient
- router: ForeignKey to RouterConfiguration
- vpn: ForeignKey to Vpn
- cert: ForeignKey to Cert

Vpn
# other fields

Cert
# (stores x509 certificates)
# other fields
```

The through model `VpnClient` has only one additional field, a `ForeignKey` to `Cert`, but I want `VpnClient` to automatically create a `Cert` instance without user interaction and until here there is no problem.

The problem comes in the Django Admin, because as far as I understood, it is not possible to use the classic many2many widget when using a through model:

> When you specify an intermediary model using the through argument to a
>   `ManyToManyField`, the admin will not display a widget by default. This
>   is because each instance of that intermediary model requires more
>   information than could be displayed in a single widget, and the layout
>   required for multiple widgets will vary depending on the intermediate
>   model.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models

But I don't want the user to insert any extra information. I just want to be able to control the model so it can perform a series of actions automatically.

So my question is: is it possible to have the classic admin widget with a custom through model? If there's no easy solution maybe I could try with a custom widget? Or maybe there is an alternative way to accomplish what I need?

**PS**: apparently there's a ticket for this use case: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12203

Comment: Can you describe the user workflow you wish to achieve? Is that something that belongs in the admin (i.e. should you create custom views to prevent end-users from accessing more than they need or make it simpler)? Is that something that could be done using [admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) ?

Comment: @raphv the user interaction is not different than the classic many-to-many admin widget, I just want the user to select the VPNs from the select list checkbox, then the system must create what it needs automatically